# How to make array of textboxes accept only specific alphabets?

Tags: c#

i am using visual studio c#.net winform and i have 2d array of 81 textboxes. . . i can't figured out how it is possible to make these textboxes accept only specific alphabet. . . can any one please show me the code. . .
THanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "specific alphabets"?

Comment: i want textboxes to only accept alphabets from A-I

Answer (score 2):

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    List<char> chrs = new List<char>{'1', '2', '3'};
    if (!chrs.Contains(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ToList method extension method?

Comment: @Anton: ToList() is a Linq extension method. As long as you have refenced System.Linq in your using statements you should have access to this.